# Fixing moc.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: visual-studio, qt, rename

I can't get my program to compile in x86 mode, but x64 works fine. It gives me this error:

```
1>  '"E:\Code\CommonEx\QT\4.8.2-vs10\bin\moc.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

However, I don't even have an E drive any more, and I don't use Qt 4.8.2 any more!

So my question is this: Why is the compiler trying to use this path and where on earth is this path getting stored?

---

Here is more background information about my setup. I'm using VS 2015 Professional with the Qt5Package extension version 1.3.9.

At the bottom of my .vcxproj this section can be found:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
<VisualStudio>
  <UserProperties MocDir=".\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)" UicDir=".\GeneratedFiles" QtVersion="5.6.0" Qt5Version_x0020_Win32="5.6.0-vs2015-x86" Qt5Version_x0020_x64="5.6.0-vs2015-x64" />
</VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

(This looks pretty normal to me)

My Qt5 settings page looks like:

[image: qt5 settings]

I'm 100% sure the paths are correct, and this looks pretty normal to me as well.

My Project's Qt settings look like:

[image: project qt settings]

(Again, this looks pretty normal to me)

And here is my environment variables table (note, QTDIR is NOT specified):

[image: environment vars]

(Because I'm using the Qt extension, my understanding is that it isn't necessary to set an environment variable in this case.)

OK, so far so good. Now here's the kicker.  I deleted my .user file and then built in x86 and x64 modes.  This is the user file that was generated:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(PATH)    </LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <QTDIR>C:\repos\CommonEx\QT\5.6.0-vs2015-x64</QTDIR>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(PATH)    </LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <QTDIR>C:\repos\CommonEx\QT\5.6.0-vs2015-x64</QTDIR>
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(PATH)    </LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(PATH)    </LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I can clearly see that the tag for QTDIR under the Debug|Win32 and Release|Win32 sections is not defined!

I have considered using a property sheet and setting up a QTDIR variable, but I don't know if that would conflict with the one that Qt Extension is setting up and I'd hate to have it being tweaked in two different places.

Why is QTDIR not getting added to the .user file for the 32 bit ones, but it exists for the 64 bit ones?  And why is it that if QTDIR isn't defined in the user file, it defaults to some path I used a long time ago. And where is *that* path stored?

I'll award points to anyone who answers the first one (why are the x86 ones not generated) since that one is the most important.  The other two are icing on the cake :-)

Answer (score 2):

So I wrote this whole thing up and as I was proofreading it, the answer dawned on me. Although the situation is probably not very common, the question and answer may be of use to someone else so there's no sense in throwing it all away.

I am aware of a bug that occurred in older version of visual studio where:

```
<QTDIR>C:\repos\CommonEx\QT\5.6.0-vs2015-x64</QTDIR>
```

must be defined before < LocalDebuggerEnvironment > in the .user file.  THIS IS NOT that case - since QTDIR is not being defined at all!

What happened was, in Visual Studio, I had renamed the solution platform:

[image: rename solution platform]

Well... that royally confused the Qt extension for Visual Studio!

In order to fix it, I had to remove Qt completely from the Visual Studio project by deleting the < ProjectExtensions > tag and everything in it from the .vcxproj file. Then I had to turn it back into a Qt project by right clicking on the project and selecting "Convert to Qt Add-in Project". Then I set the qt project settings to use the 5.6.0 version.  Once I did that... build... and success! The .user file now has a QTDIR section for the x86 modes and everything builds as it should.

The strange thing is... I have three different computers that I use to work on that solution. I had to perform the above procedure for ALL of them. Apparently the Qt Extension somehow stores some internal settings related to the platform name that are not part of the project. Just the process of removing Qt from the project and adding it again is all that is needed. The project itself does get modified, but the modifications are minor and don't affect anything.  The real fix happens in some internal settings somewhere.

As to where those mystical settings are stored... I think I found the QTDIR one - the old qt vs add-in used to create a file called Qt4VSPropertySheet.props, which contained that really old Qt path. I don't think the newer version of the add-in or the extension use that anymore.